# Assembling char array with different integers to resemble date and time

Tags: c++, char, int

I need to create a method that returns a char array in a date and time format.

```
class DateTime {

    int *_day, *_month, *_year, *_hours, *_minutes;

public:

    DateTime(int day = 1, int month = 1, int year = 2000, int hours = 0, int minutes = 0) {
        _day= new int(day);
        _month= new int(month);
        _year= new int(year);
        _hours = new int(hours);
        _minutes= new int(minutes);
    }
}

char * ToCharArray() {

}
```

In the given class assignment I have to use int pointers and assign their values in main.

I have tried stringstream to convert the the integers to chars and then tried to asseble them into the array in a meaningful way, but it didn't work out for me.

I tried to manually enter the values into the array by using

```
temp[0] = '0' + *_date;
```

but since some dates are double digit, figuring out the dots and spaces in the format would be too hard.

The expected result would be something like this:

```
DateTime date1(19, 6, 2018, 10, 15); 
cout << date1.ToCharArray() << endl;

// outputs: 19.6.2018 10:15
```

Comment: Aside from the formatting issue being asked, the shown code is either not the actual code, or the shown class cannot possibly work. Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're asking about, instead of fake-looking class declarations that cannot possibly work, at all.

Comment: Why are you using `int` pointers as class members of your `DateTime` class? Also why are you rolling your own? C++ already has [utilities for Date/Time handling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: And instead of inventing yet another timestamp. Use [std::chrono::time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Comment: If *figuring out the dots and spaces in the format* is too hard, then why not use the standard `std::put_time` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: stringstream was correct.  Why did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to support you.

First and most important: In modern C++ you should never (or as minimal as possible) use raw pointers for memory management. Always use std::unique:ptr or std::shared_ptr.

The risk of creating memory leaks by using raw pointers for dynamic memory management is too high. For your purposes, having a closed class DateTime with protected date/time members, I cannot imagine any reasonable use case for having pointers at all. If it is for academic purposes, then OK. Else, there is simply no need.

If you want to use pointers and dynamic memory allocation, then you must delete the newed memory in the destructor of the class. Othewise you have guaranteed memory leaks. And do not forget to initialize pointers with nullptr.

Now to your question:

If you just want to output your class DateTime to any ostream, then you should overide the << operator in your class. You can see the example in the below code.

If you want to put the data of your class in a string, then use a std::string. You should not use a char *.

If you still want to use a char *, I also added an example. But please be aware. That is read only. And only valid, as ling as dateTimeString is in scope.

So, agin, try to avoid using raw pointers. There is no need.

In the below example I put 2 classes with, in the beginning, the more meaningful approach without pointers (class DateTime1) and a class with pointers(class DateTime2). For tests you can select the class to be used in the using statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

class DateTime1     // Version 1
{
public:
    DateTime1() {}      // Default. Does nothing. Use standard default values
    DateTime1(int d, int m, int y, int h, int min) : day(d), month(m), year(y), hours(h), minutes(min) {}
    // Option 1. Overwrite the ostream operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DateTime1& dt) { return os << dt.day << '.' << dt.month << '.' << dt.year << ' ' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << dt.hours << ':' << std::setw(2) << dt.minutes; }
    // Option 2. Create a std String
    std::string toString() {std::ostringstream oss; oss << day << '.' << month << '.' << year << ' ' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << hours << ':' << std::setw(2) << minutes; return oss.str();}
protected:
    int day{ 1 };   int month{ 1 }; int year{ 1970 };   int hours{ 0 }; int minutes{ 0 };
};


class DateTime2     // Version 2
{
public:
    explicit DateTime2(int d, int m, int y, int h, int min) : day(new int(d)), month(new int(m)), year(new int(y)), hours(new int(h)), minutes(new int(min)) {}
    // MUST delete dynamically allocated memory
    ~DateTime2() { delete day; delete month; delete year; delete hours; delete minutes; }

    // Option 1. Overwrite the ostream operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DateTime2& dt) { return os << *dt.day << '.' << *dt.month << '.' << *dt.year << ' ' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << *dt.hours << ':' << std::setw(2) << *dt.minutes; }
    // Option 2. Create a std String
    std::string toString() { std::ostringstream oss; oss << *day << '.' << *month << '.' << *year << ' ' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << *hours << ':' << std::setw(2) << *minutes; return oss.str(); }
protected:
    int* day{ nullptr }; int* month{ nullptr }; int* year{ nullptr };   int* hours{ nullptr };  int* minutes{ nullptr };
};

using DateTime = DateTime2;   // Seletc DateTime1 or DateTime2

int main()
{
    std::cout << DateTime(19, 6, 2018, 10, 15) << '\n';

    // or
    DateTime date1(19, 6, 2018, 10, 15);    // Call the contructor
    std::cout << date1 << '\n';

    // or
    std::string dateTimeString{ date1.toString() };     // Initialize variable dateTimeString
    const char* dateTimeCharP{ dateTimeString.c_str() };

    std::cout << dateTimeString << '\n';
    std::cout << dateTimeCharP << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps